# CSS Responsive is weird for my website, width auto

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, responsive

I have done a website in ReactJS and SASS. Everything went well until I tried to make it responsive. The width is weird on smaller devices.

This is the website: https://uidea3.netlify.app/

Help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your `.header` class has fixed width of `1024px`. Remove it and the website will not overflow. If you need to make it responsive then you can add the media query like this. You will need to figure out the correct breakpoints for your use case you may refer to the [bootstrap breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/overview/)

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1023px) {
  .header {
     width: 1024px;
     ...rest of properties
   }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
  .header {
     width: 100%;
     ...rest of properties
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Explore on `react-media` a package available in npm. It will render component or element based on your configured device size.